# How to complete 3D Export PCB in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers

I know how to export a STEP file in Altium, but is there a way to export the whole PCB, just as it is displayed in Altium's screen? I mean with the traces, vias, components, etc.

Comment: I know this is old, but for any future readers, Ivan's answer seems to do just this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/369433/41856

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't a way to export that.

You only can export the 3D models included in your PCB.

There are some tricks for solve this issue but they are really hard and IMHO they don't solve the problem. You can find them in the links below

Here are some topics from Altium Design Forum (you must be registered to see them):

http://forum.live.altium.com/posts/193722

http://forum.live.altium.com/posts/193565

http://forum.live.altium.com/posts/192662

Update:
The format Parasolid allows to export the copper features and Altium export the PCB 3D model in that format

Comment: I did not solve it, and as a matter of fact I searched online furthermore and found that its impossible to do in Altium. I am not at home now so I can't attach any picture, I am sorry.

Comment: I dont have a registration...

Comment: @mFeinstein It's free!

Comment: Not for me I guess...

Comment: Sorry, but I think that it's free for everybody.

Comment: Every time I try to register the website says it will be under review and they will send me a contact in the future...if it's different for you, could you explain me how to do?

Comment: It's free for subscribers .. which you obviously aren't (or talk to your rep) - which then leads to the question where you got Altium Designer from ...

Answer (score 4):

The best way that I have found that actually yields good results is to upload the design to oshpark.com, they have a script that automatically converts gerber files into a 2D images (front and back) for preview, with all of the silkscreen, pads, and traces in fairly high resolution. The file is generated with purple mask, I usually use Photoshop's replace color function to change the mask to green. Here is a corner of one of my boards:

[image]

Then I generate the step file from altium and import it into Solidworks and simply add the aforementioned images to the board surfaces. I assume that this would work with any 3D rendering tool that reads step files. It yields really good results.

Here is a part of a fully rendered example:

[image]

Comment: Good idea on using OshPark's render! I have used almost the same technique before, it just was an Altium printscreen instead, for the image to be placed as a decal on SolidWorks.

Answer (score 4):

There is such Tools-> Legacy Tools-> Legacy 3D View.

Running.

Click Tools-> Export.

There we disable everything except text and silkscreen, otherwise we will never wait for the render to finish.

As a result we get STEP of pure silk-screen printing (by the way, it can also unload the trace there). This STEP is loaded to its motherboard, like the usual 3D_Body, directly on top of the board.

Comment: I never knew this! I've been looking for this sort of tool for ages, I had no idea it already existed under "Legacy Tools"! This should definitely be the accepted answer!

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the "Legacy Tools" were removed from AD18 =(

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

[Module 20: Interfacing to 3D Mechanical CAD](http://www.altium.com/files/training/Module%2020%20-%203D%20Mechanical%20CAD.pdf)

It describes how to do this to export to CAD.

Comment: Yes I know about it...but still it isnt a complete export..as I said, I wanted to export the traces, and the PCB color..ARES do it, and Altium is a lot better than ARES..

Answer (score 0):

CADD EDGE sells a Desktop EDA plugin for Altium that provides full integration with SolidWorks.
More information can be found here:
http://www.caddedge.com/altium/desktop-eda-solidworks-modeler-for-altium-designer/

Comment: on the video it appears to be still without the traces..

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to export directly with traces etc... If you need a faithful pcb render you could use rendering software such a Keyshot or 3D Studio Max where you can add material properties to each part including the PCB. In the case of the PCB you can make it a colored fiberglass material and then you can add 'lables' to the PCB material ('label' is just lingo for "flat" 2D art). The label could be a simple .png/.jpg export of the traces and/or silkscreen layers.

Comment: Yeah, I know...but the whole purpose of the question is to avoid this trouble all together