# How to export step 3D with silkscreen in Altium

Tags: altium

In Altium Designer I can just export 3D step without copper, silkscreen or pads. Is there a solution to export the PCB as it is in the 3D view?

There is a solution in this [Related Topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51255/how-to-complete-3d-export-pcb-in-altium/369433#369433).

According to what is written there, I need to follow these steps:

Tools-> Legacy Tools-> Legacy 3D View

However, the version of Altium I am using does not have the Legacy Tool. I am using version 22.11.1 which is the latest version of Altium.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Because silkscreen cannot have 3D model.

For components you can define 3D models and embed them into the footprint library. But it's not a thing that can be applied for silkscreen.

What you can do is to export the board as 3D pdf. It'll contain vias, stack up, tracks, everything...

Comment: So, combining 2D and 3D in SolidWorks is the most logical solution. Am I right?

Comment: @harmonica One of my ex-colleagues used to use the entire PCB's DXF-export as a base and apply some sort of "extrusion" to silkscreen. Try if it works for you.